# All methods run in worker thread?

Tags: android, intentservice, locationlistener

If I create a class that subclasses IntentService and implements LocationListener all the methods of this class will run in the worker thread ? Or only the onHandleIntent() method runs in the worker thread?

Comment: Only onHandleIntent... IntentService is not a good choice for this... First, there is no need for another thread working with LocationListener. Second,  IntentService is for one time job on worker thread

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Selvin . Do you know how I can make all the methods of a service run in a worker thread?

Comment: First question is What for?....  But if you wana do it just start new thread.

Comment: I want to create a service that implements LocationListener , like i've described in the question. But I can't find out how to make that service run in a thred that is not the UIthread .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of where a method is run is defined by where it is called and not from the class it is defined.

The onHandleIntent method is called in the WorkerThread, so if you call any methods from the onHandleIntent, it will run in the WorkerThread.

If you call any method from the service directly in the UI thread, the method will run in the UI Thread.